# How to solve the logarithmic equation $\ln(x + 4) = 6$?

Tags: logarithms

I would like to learn the steps for solving this math problem. One of my classmates gave me this problem, and I need help solving it.

$\ln(x+4)=6$

Comment: To eliminate a natural log you raise e that power.  So $\ln x = y \implies e^{\ln x} = e^y \implies x = e^y$.  This is how you *always* solve them.  So this is $x+4 = e^6$ which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 3):

$\ln(x+4)=6\Leftrightarrow x+4=e^{6}\Leftrightarrow x=e^{6}-4.$